# Troublesome Limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x \geq 1.$ I am trying to find

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n + i^x}$$

My attempt: For $x = 1$ this is a Riemann sum

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n + i} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1 + \frac{i}{n}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x} = \ln2.$$

For $x > 1$, I'm not sure how to proceed or if the limit exists for all $x$.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x>1$ the answer is $0$.

Choose a number $y$ strictly between $\frac1x$ and $1$, and split the sum at $n^y$. The first half of the sum is
$$
\sum_{i\le n^y} \frac1{n+i^x} \le \sum_{i\le n^y} \frac1n \le n^{y-1},
$$
while the second half of the sum is
$$
\sum_{n^y<i\le n} \frac1{n+i^x} \le \sum_{n^y<i\le n} \frac1{i^x} \le \sum_{n^y<i\le n} \frac1{(n^y)^x} \le \sum_{1\le i\le n} \frac1{n^{yx}} = n^{1-yx}.
$$
Since both $y-1$ and $1-yx$ are negative, we see that
$$
0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{n+i^x} \le \lim_{n\to\infty} ( n^{y-1} + n^{1-yx} ) =0 .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to answer.
Let$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{n+k^{\alpha}}}\ \ \ \ \left( \alpha >1 \right) 
$$
Converting it to an integral and estimate the error.
$$\begin{aligned}S&=\int_0^n{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{n+x^{\alpha}}}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\int_k^{k+1}{\left( \frac{1}{n+k^{\alpha}}-\frac{1}{n+x^{\alpha}} \right) \text{d}x}}
\\
&=I(n)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\int_0^1{\frac{\left( k+x \right) ^{\alpha}-k^{\alpha}}{\left( n+k^{\alpha} \right) \left( n+\left( k+x \right) ^{\alpha} \right)}\mathrm{d}x}}
\\
&=I(n) +\Delta( n)\end{aligned} $$
To estimate the error term, first introduce a variable $\beta$. This introduction splits the series into 2 parts. $$\begin{aligned}
\Delta ( n ) &=O\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\int_0^1{\frac{\alpha \left( k+1 \right) ^{\alpha -1}}{\left( n+k^{\alpha} \right) ^2}\text{d}x}} \right) \\&=O\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{k^{\alpha -1}}{\left( n+k^{\alpha} \right) ^2}} \right) \\&=O\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n^{\beta}}{+\sum_{k=n^{\beta}}^{n-1}{\frac{k^{\alpha -1}}{\left( n+k^{\alpha} \right) ^2}}} \right) 
\\&=O\left( \frac{n^{\alpha \beta}}{n^2} \right) +O\left( \int_{n^{\beta}}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{\alpha -1}}{x^{2\alpha}}\text{d}x} \right) \\&=O\left( n^{\alpha \beta -2} \right) +O\left( n^{-\alpha \beta} \right)\end{aligned}$$Let$$\alpha \beta -2=-\alpha \beta ,\ \beta =\frac{1}{\alpha}.$$Hence$$
\color{red}{\Delta \left( n \right) =O\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) }
$$

Finally, we prove $I(n)=o(1)$. Fix an $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$,
$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{n\to\infty}I(n)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{n\mathrm{d}x}{n+(nx)^\alpha}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+n^{\alpha-1}x^\alpha}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\varepsilon\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+n^{\alpha-1}x^\alpha}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\varepsilon^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+n^{\alpha-1}x^\alpha}\\
&\le \varepsilon+0=\varepsilon\end{aligned}$$
Due to the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$, $I(n)=o(1)$. These prove the original limit is zero.

#### APPENDIX

We can actually go further using this method by forming a better estimation of $I(n)$.
$$I(n)={}_2F_1\left( 1,\frac{1}{\alpha};1+\frac{1}{\alpha};-n^{\alpha -1} \right)$$
Using hypergeometric function and its asymptotic properties (it is not necessary to use it but it is more convenient), we immediately get
$$I(n)=\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\csc \frac{\pi}{\alpha}\cdot n^{1/\alpha -1}+O\left( n^{1-\alpha} \right)$$
Hence, $$\color{red}{S=\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\csc \frac{\pi}{\alpha}\cdot n^{1/\alpha -1}+O\left(n^{\max\{1-\alpha,-1\}}\right)}$$

Comment: This problem also have an easier way to obtain the leading term.

Answer (score 0):

For any $n\gt0$ and any $x\gt0$, the function $f(u)=1/(n+u^x)$ is strictly decreasing for $u\gt0$. Therefore

$$0\lt\sum_{i=1}^n{1\over n+i^x}\lt\int_0^n{dt\over n+t^x}=\int_0^1{n\,du\over n+n^xu^x}=\int_0^1{du\over1+n^{x-1}u^x}$$

For any $\epsilon\gt0$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1{du\over1+n^{x-1}u^x}
&=\int_0^\epsilon{du\over1+n^{x-1}u^x}+\int_\epsilon^1{du\over1+n^{x-1}u^x}\\
&\lt\int_0^\epsilon du+\int_\epsilon^1{du\over n^{x-1}u^x}\\
&=\epsilon+{1\over(x-1)n^{x-1}}(\epsilon^{1-x}-1)
\end{align}$$

and thus, if $x\gt1$,

$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n{1\over n+i^x}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\epsilon+{1\over(x-1)n^{x-1}}(\epsilon^{1-x}-1)\right)=\epsilon$$

for all $\epsilon\gt0$, hence the limit must be $0$.